# set ansible_user for specific task in role

Tags: ansible

I am stumbling over setting the ansible_user (or remote_user) for a specific task in a role.

What works fine is to set the ansible_user in host or group vars and the role and tasks are using this user for ssh into the server.

What I want to achieve is to set an remote user for a specific task in a role.

So I have a main.yml where different tasks are included.

For one if them I want to set the ansible_user: user2

But I tried different variants, every time I execute the play with this role the ansible_user, defined in group or host vars will be used:

```
- name: "include user_create.yml"
  include_tasks: 
    file: "user_create.yml"
    apply:
      become: yes
      remote_user: user2
  vars:
    - become: yes
    - remote_user: user2
    - ansible_user: user2
  tags: 
    - user_create
```

I tried almost all variants of the above settings but no luck.

Does anyone has an idea?

UPDATE:
This should work according to Zeitounator but did not work for me either:

```
- name: "include user_create.yml"
  include_tasks: 
    file: "user_create.yml"
    apply: 
      ansible_user: user2      

  tags: 
    - user_create
```

UPDATE2:

So i was able to set a different user to a task like this:

```
- name: "include user_create.yml"
  include_tasks: 
    file: "user_create.yml"
    #apply: 
    #  become: yes
  vars:
    ansible_user: user2
  tags: 
    - user_create
```

but only if there is no ansibl_user defined in all.yml.

So from my understanding a block or task var should overwrite a group var (all.yml is a group var from my understanding).

Comment: `remote_user` is a play level option. In all other places your use `ansible_user`. Just change that in your `apply` stanza for your include, drop the var (which are redundant, unused as applied to the include itself and not the included tasks, and should be a dict anyway and not a list).

Comment: So this would be something like this:
- name: "include user_create.yml"
  include_tasks: 
    file: "user_create.yml"
    apply: { 
        ansible_user: root
      }
  tags: 
    - user_create

but this don't work either. 
By the way: are you sure a dict is needed for apply? A sorry I missunderstood you. You meant the vars should be a dict...

Answer (score 0):

`remote_user` is a play level stanza. The variable to use elsewhere is `ansible_user`. I suspect what you want exactly is:

```yaml
- name: "include user_create.yml"
  include_tasks: 
    file: "user_create.yml"
    apply:
      become: yes
      ansible_user: user2
      tags:
        - user_create
  tags: 
    - always
```

Comment: this is exactly what I tried but it won't work. I set the ansible_user in a all.yml group var file. But this should be not interfering from my understanding.